# Connecting to MySQL via JDBC: unable to find a suitable driver

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following error in connecting to MySQL via JDBC:

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (Unable to find a suitable driver).
```

I am using ubuntu 21.04. when I download the jar file from mysql website it download as '.deb' file. But in netbeans it ask zip files. how to solve it?
And I got another error which tell that "bean-binding " is missing

Comment: You will need MySQL driver's Jar files.

Comment: i.e. not a .deb file.